# Trying to embed a PowerBI report in a WebSharper Client Server F# application

Tags: f#, powerbi-embedded, websharper, assembly-binding-redirect

I started from the downloaded PowerBIEmbedded_AppOwnsData C# razor demo, which works as expected. Then I tried to do the same starting with a WebSharper project, but didn't have success so far. The problem occurs when I try to istantiate a PowerBIClient object.

First the working C#

```
...
// Create a user password cradentials.
var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);
// Authenticate using created credentials
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientId, credential);
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
// Create a Power BI Client object. It will be used to call Power BI APIs.
using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
{
...
```

And now the F# code that doesn't work:

```
...
let credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password)
let authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl)
let authenticationResult = 
    authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientId, credential)
    |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
let tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer")
let client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials)
...
```

The project compiles without errors, but at runtime it generates an exception;
When the let client = ... is executed I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly 
reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Root/Project/NCF/NCF.BPP1/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Root\Project\NCF\NCF.BPP1\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: 
C:\Root\Project\NCF\NCF.BPP1\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
\\aunpmfps1\mydocs$\Franco.Tiveron\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
LOG: Attempting download of new URL 
file:///C:/Users/franco.tiveron/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET 
Files/vs/6323d2e3/834678d6/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL 
file:///C:/Users/franco.tiveron/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET 
Files/vs/6323d2e3/834678d6/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL 
file:///C:/Root/Project/NCF/NCF.BPP1/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing 
terminated.
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe you'll need to set up an assembly redirect in your `app.config` file, but I don't know precisely how to do that. If you're using Paket to get your NuGet package dependencies, I know that Paket has a feature to do that for you. How are you fetching dependencies in your project?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found that adding a redirection to web.config fixes the issue:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.1.0" newVersion="4.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <!-- Manual add BEGIN -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- Manual add END -->

    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.web>
  <!-- NOTE: remove debug="true" to serve compressed JavaScript -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="WebSharper.RemotingModule" type="WebSharper.Web.RpcModule, WebSharper.Web" />
      <add name="WebSharper.Sitelets" type="WebSharper.Sitelets.HttpModule, WebSharper.Sitelets" />
    </modules>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank you very much to @rmunn for the hint.